How to compute confidence interval xgboost regressor?
I have time series data to predict values for the next 6 months.
I have an xgboost model that predicts the six individual months, for the business what is important is that the cumulative value of predicted values are close to the cumulative values of the true values for the period.
I was asked to add a confidence interval of 90% to my model. How can I do this?

Does this answer your question? How to get a confidence score for predictions?

I would also recommend reading this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608844/intuitive-explanation-of-conformal-prediction
